# How to ensure localculture is used for interface but not floating point values in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, localization

I have a WinForms application on russian system. For the number of reasons, i prefer using floating-values formatting from `InvariantCulture` (which is English).

Following found solutions in the internet, i have set `InvariantCulture` as a default culture for the application. However, as a result, localised versions of forms (with russian text) are never loaded.

How can i ensure that forms with russian text are automatically loaded on russian machines, but for floating point values string conversions `InvariantCulture` behaviour is used?

Comment: Set russian locale and then change number format.

Comment: Add that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter any property of `CultureInfo` after creating it for specific culture, e.g.:

```
// create culture with default values for russian
var culture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
// change number format
culture.NumberFormat = new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = "." };
// set culture
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

After that you don't need to specify culture for parsing/formatting:

```
var test = double.Parse("1.234"); // would throw without changing NumberFormat
MessageBox.Show(test.ToString()); // output: 1.234
```